# Retrieve overlap widths with Bioconductor

Tags: r, bioconductor, genomicranges

I want to retrieve all overlaps between two sets of genomic intervals (GRanges) using Bioconductor. I am interested in the widths of the resulting overlapping ranges.

In cases with discontinuous ranges, `intersect()` works, but I am interested in the case where both sets contain contiguous ranges (no gaps).

I am using the findOverlaps function as in the example below:

```r
gr1 <- GRanges(seqnames="chr2", ranges=IRanges(c(1, 11, 21, 31), c(10, 20, 30, 40)))
gr2 <- GRanges(seqnames="chr2", ranges=IRanges(c(1, 5, 15), c(4, 14, 30)))
hits <- findOverlaps(gr1, gr2)
```

This code yields the following intersections in a "Hits" object:

```
Hits object with 5 hits and 0 metadata columns:
      queryHits subjectHits
      <integer>   <integer>
  [1]         1           1
  [2]         1           2
  [3]         2           2
  [4]         2           3
  [5]         3           3
  -------
  queryLength: 4 / subjectLength: 3
```

But I could not find a way to extract the intersections widths from the resulting object.

It this the wrong approach ?

> Note: Using `intersect(gr1, gr2)` in this case yields a single contiguous overlap range spanning the whole chromosome, but I want each overlap to be returned independently, just like findOverlaps does.

Comment: Please add a representative output example.

Comment: Thanks, I just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst `intersect` is sort of doing what you want, it merges adjacent overlaps together which is not what you want I suppose. There doesn't seem to be dedicated `Grange` function to do this out of the box, but you could go through all overlapping pairs resulting from `findOverlap` and calculate it's widths using [pintersect](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/IRanges/versions/2.0.1/topics/setops-methods):

> punion, pintersect, psetdiff and pgap are generic functions that compute the element-wise (aka "parallel") union, intersection, (asymmetric!) difference and gap between each element in x and its corresponding element in y.

> "pintersect"(x, y, resolve.empty=c("none", "max.start", "start.x"), ...) # x, y   IRanges objects.

```
hits <- findOverlaps(gr1, gr2)

width(pintersect(gr1[queryHits(hits)],
                 gr2[subjectHits(hits)]))
[1]  2  6  4  6 10
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `pintersect` only computes the intersection between pairs of ranges at the same position. (e.g. 2nd vs 2nd). This implies you have the same number of ranges in `gr1` and `gr2`. I am interested in the all-vs-all intersection. I will update my example to make that clearer, sorry.

Comment: Thanks that answers the question :) The only issue is that the R loop is super slow. In my case I have 468,000 intersections and it's still running after 10mins. I have found an alternative which runs in 0.1 sec, but it is imperfect as I have to truncate intervals by 1bp (slightly wrong results):

`mywidths <- width(intersect(narrow(gr1, start=2), narrow(gr2, start=2))); comp_df <- data.frame(feat1 = ol@from, feat2 = ol@to, size = mywidths)`

Comment: That a good point. I've added another possibly quicker solution, hope that works!

Comment: That last solution is a great idea, thanks !

Comment: If it works for, I'd consolidate the answer since the first iterations are superflous then :)